# How to emit event in Vue.js depending on the width of the screen

Tags: vue.js

I've got the following code from my sidebar. When any link is clicked, I'm also emitting an event to my root component and then invoking a function to hide the sidebar. This is working well but now I would like the event to be emitted only when the width of the screen is less than 768px so that I can emit the event only when I want to invoke the function.

```
 <div class="side-links">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <router-link @click="$emit('navLinkClicked')" :to="{ name: 'Home' }"
            >Home</router-link
          >
        </li>
        <li>
          <router-link @click="$emit('navLinkClicked')" :to="{ name: 'Blog' }"
            >Blog</router-link
          >
        </li>

        <li>
          <router-link @click="$emit('navLinkClicked')" :to="{ name: 'About' }"
            >About</router-link
          >
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `window.innerWidth` to check the width of the current viewport. Global scope variables however is not available in the template, because its scoped to your component. You can either create a handler method:

```js
<script>
  methods: {
    onNavLinkClicked() {
      if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
        this.$emit('navLinkClicked')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
<template>
  <div class="side-links">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <router-link
          @click="onNavLinkClicked"
          :to="{ name: 'Home' }"
        >
          Home
        </router-link
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

or create a computed variable that defines if the width is below the treshold:

```js
<script>
  computed: {
    isMobile() {
      return window.innerWidth < 768;
    }
  }
</script>
<template>
  <div class="side-links">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <router-link
          @click="isMobile ? $emit('navLinkClicked') : null"
          :to="{ name: 'Home' }"
        >
          Home
        </router-link
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Personally i'd go with the first option, so you'll only have to do the check once.

In Vue 2 it is also recommended to use [kebab-case for event names](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html).